# mp3gain - getting information from the commandline

Tags: php, shell

I am using mp3gain ( http://mp3gain.sourceforge.net/ ) from the commandline, and want to get the volume level for single-track files

I'd like to either:

-- use some flag I can't work out that will return only the volume

or

-- figure out how to parse the -o flag output with shellscript or php so I can reliably extract that number

TIA!

Comment: what do you get now, should be fairly easy to parse

Comment: using the -o flag, it seems to be a multi-line output & so exec() only captures the last line, and I can't capture all of it with passthru()

cf: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/mp3gain.1.html

Comment: you inspired me, though, and figured out one thing I was doing wrong - had $output = exec('...') instead of exec('...', $output). So now I can parse easily enough. Would still be nice if there were a flag for getting volume directly  (this only gives me an offset)

Comment: its open source, you could always contribute. Also you could look into the actually libraries used and possibly write some sort of extension rather than shell out.

Comment: Specifically http://mp3gain.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/mp3gain/mp3gain/gain_analysis.h?revision=1.3&view=markup looks like they expose GetTitleGain as a public method.

Comment: yes, perhaps someday I'll go learn C so I can make a small contribution to some minor library I'm using one time for a client :-) I'm merely asking if anyone knows of a flag, not complaining about it. I don't believe they do that, only other stats

Answer (score 0):

In Aug 2022, `mp3gain` output doesn't include volume. Here's what I when using the `-x` switch for my favorite song *foo*:

```
foo.mp3
Recommended "Track" dB change: -11.390000        
Recommended "Track" mp3 gain change: -8
Max PCM sample at current gain: 82207.601562
Max mp3 global gain field: 189
Min mp3 global gain field: 133

Recommended "Album" dB change for all files: -11.390000
Recommended "Album" mp3 gain change for all files: -8
```

Maybe the *mp3 global gain field* can be interpreted as volume?